# How to get content via url-request?

Tags: java, android

I write application which must show page content(text and images) via url-request. My task requires to do it manually, for example variant such as **WebView webView.loadUrl(url.toString());** is not suitable. How to solve this task in another way?

Comment: I need to parse content-stream

Comment: Define 'manually'.  Which classes are you allowed to use?

Comment: I can't answer exactly which classes I can to use. But my task is not allowed to go in such way as, for example, WebView webView.loadUrl(url.toString()). Where external browser executes all my tasks instead me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `HTTPClient`. something like this.

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) {
  InputStream content = null;
  try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    content = response.getEntity().getContent(); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);
  }
    return content; //url content is here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to get an image or an text from content-variable for example?